# Calling a json function in mvc3 after jquery validation

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am very new to this so please bear with me I have an mvc view with a text box and a submit button. I would like to know how to post Json data to an action result AFTER successful Jquery validation.

any links or tip would be greatfully appreciated.

Comment: I'd say the first advice would be: use google with very similar terms to those you used on this question :)

Comment: Agree with Claudio, also read [ask]

Comment: search for jquery json ajax

Comment: Thanks for the help I took your advice and found a soloution